# How to unit-test a Fantom DAO class that uses AlienFactory's afIoc and afMorphia frameworks?

Tags: mongodb, inversion-of-control, fantom

Say I have a simple Fantom app to retrieve data from a MongoDB database. The app uses afIoc (AlienFactory's IoC framework) and afMorphia (AlienFactory's MongoDB framework). I have a simple Entity called Foo and a DAO class (FooDao) to retrieve Foo entities from the database. I want to test the DAO class using fant command but I'm getting the error below. What am I doing wrong or is there a better way to write the test?. Please note that this app doesn't use afBedSheet web framework.

```
TEST FAILED
afIoc::IocErr: No dependency matches type sys::Type.
Ioc Operation Trace:
  [ 1] Injecting dependencies into fields of testAfIoc::FooDaoTest
  [ 2] Injecting dependencies into fields of testAfIoc::FooDaoTest
  [ 3] Looking for dependency of type testAfIoc::FooDao?
  [ 4] Creating REAL Service 'testAfIoc::FooDao'
  [ 5] Creating 'testAfIoc::FooDao' via ctor autobuild
  [ 6] Injecting dependencies into fields of testAfIoc::FooDao
  [ 7] Looking for dependency of type afMorphia::Datastore?
  [ 8] Creating REAL Service 'afMorphia::Datastore'
  [ 9] Creating 'afMorphia::Datastore' via ctor autobuild
  [10] Determining injection parameters for afMorphia::DatastoreImpl sys::Void make(sys::Type type, afMongo::Database database, |sys::This->sys::Void| in)
Stack Trace:
  afIoc::Utils.stackTraceFilter (Utils.fan:50)
  afIoc::RegistryImpl.injectIntoFields (RegistryImpl.fan:253)
  testAfIoc::FooDaoTest.setup (FooDaoTest.fan:17)
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:483)
  fan.sys.Method.invoke (Method.java:559)
  fan.sys.Method$MethodFunc.callList (Method.java:204)
  fan.sys.Method.callList (Method.java:138)
  fanx.tools.Fant.runTest (Fant.java:190)
  fanx.tools.Fant.test (Fant.java:110)
  fanx.tools.Fant.test (Fant.java:32)
  fanx.tools.Fant.run (Fant.java:284)
  fanx.tools.Fant.main (Fant.java:327)

Time: 377ms

Failed:
  testAfIoc::FooDaoTest.testFindAll

***
*** 1 FAILURES [1 tests, 0 methods, 0 verifies]
***
```

This is how my classes look like (explicit "using" statements to show what classes come from what Fantom pods):

fan/AppModule.fan

```
using afIoc::Configuration
using afIoc::Contribute
using afIoc::ServiceDefinitions
using afIocConfig::ApplicationDefaults
using afMorphia::MorphiaConfigIds
using afMorphia::Datastore

class AppModule {

  @Contribute { serviceType=ApplicationDefaults# }
  static Void contributeAppDefaults(Configuration config) {
    config[MorphiaConfigIds.mongoUrl] = `mongodb://localhost:27017/foo`
  }

  static Void defineServices(ServiceDefinitions defs) {
    defs.add(FooDao#)
    defs.add(Datastore#)
  }

}
```

fan/Foo.fan

```
using afMorphia::Entity
using afMorphia::Property
using afBson::ObjectId

@Serializable
@Entity { name="foo" }
class Foo {

  @Property const ObjectId _id
  @Property const Str text

  new make(|This| f) { f(this) }
}
```

fan/FooDao.fan

```
using afIoc::Inject
using afMorphia::Datastore

class FooDao {

  @Inject { type=Foo# }
  Datastore? datastore

  Foo[] all() {
    (Foo[]) datastore.findAll
  }
}
```

fan/FooDaoTest.fan

```
using afIoc::Inject
using afIoc::RegistryBuilder
using afIocConfig::ConfigModule
using afMorphia::Datastore

class FooDaoTest : Test {

  @Inject
  FooDao? subject

  override Void setup() {
    registry := RegistryBuilder().addModules([
      AppModule#
      ,ConfigModule#
      ,Datastore#
    ]).build.startup
    registry.injectIntoFields(this)
  }

  Void testFindAll() {
    verifyEq ( subject.all.size, 2 )
  }
}
```

build.fan

```
#! /usr/bin/env fan

using build

class Build : BuildPod {

  new make() {
    podName = "testAfIoc"
    summary = "Testing AF IoC"
    version = Version("0.0.1")
    depends = [
      "sys 1.0+",
      "afIoc 2.0.2+",
      "afIocConfig 1.0.16+",
      "util 1.0+",
      "afMongo 1.0.0+",
      "afBson 1.0.0+",
      "concurrent 1.0.8+",
      "afMorphia 1.0.2+"
    ]
    srcDirs = [
      `fan/`,
    ]
    meta = [
      "proj.name" : "Testing Alien Factory IoC framework",
      "afIoc.module" : "testAfIoc::AppModule",
      "org.name" : "Foo",
      "org.uri"  : "http://www.example.com/"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is setup right, and the way you're testing the DAO is spot on. (Morphia doesn't need `Foo` to be `@Serializable` by the way...)

The problem is where you build the `Registry`. Because Morphia is an IoC library, you need to add Morphia's module to the registry. Also note that `Datastore` is not a module and should not be added:

In *fan/FooDaoTest.fan*

```java
using afIoc::Inject
using afIoc::RegistryBuilder
using afIocConfig::ConfigModule
using afMorphia::MorphiaModule

class FooDaoTest : Test {

  @Inject
  FooDao? subject

  override Void setup() {
    registry := RegistryBuilder()
      .addModule(AppModule#)
      .addModulesFromPod("afMorphia")
      .addModulesFromPod("afIocConfig")
      .build.startup
    registry.injectIntoFields(this)
  }

  Void testFindAll() {
    verifyEq ( subject.all.size, 2 )
  }
}
```

When building your own `Registry`, make sure all the relevant IoC modules and libraries are added.

I'm surprised that the code didn't throw a `'Datastore' Service Not Found Err` (which is more telling) - I'll look in to that...

#### Edit:

Ah, yes. In your `AppModule` there's no need to add `Datastore` as a service. All libraries should define their own services in their module, so all you should ever need to do is add that module (and maybe configure some services).

*(Morphia has a special dependency provider for building `Datastore` instances which is why it didn't work when you added it as a plain service.)*

Removing the `Datastore` definition from `AppModule` and re-running the *broken* test gives:

```
TEST FAILED
afIoc::IocErr: No service matches type afMorphia::Datastore?.
```

which is (a bit) more informative and what I would expect.

Comment: **Because Morphia is an IoC library, you need to add Morphia's module to the registry.** This is key!. Can I suggest to highlight this in afMorphia's documentation, please? And afIoc's **addModulesFromPod(Str podName)** method as well? I wouldn't have known what module to add or its name (MorphiaModule). BTW I added Datastore# to the "Modules" list after getting this message: **afIoc::IocErr: No service matches type afMorphia::Datastore?**. My bad because I didn't pay attention that it had to be an App Module, but it isn't.